# RPC Port-flapping in Active Directory

Tags: port, active-directory, rpc

**Have you ever experienced RPC port flapping in Active Directory servers?**

---

In deploying an agentless server performance tool we experienced RPC connection issues that gradually opened up over a few hours. Initially all Domain Controller RPC/WMI connections were blocked in the 2016 Forest and Domain, but, gradually, the port opened over the day until all were accessible. Now, we do see port-flapping addressed as network switch problem, but has anyone been able to troubleshoot such a port flap in AD?
We suspect competing group policies.

Comment: Port flapping is usually a term for physical ports going up/down, but RPC uses tcp/udp ports - can you add more information about what you're seeing? firewall policies are likely (though gpo runs every 45 min by default), but it depends how you attempted to block it and what you're scanning with.